# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript

I am using js file for paginate a table. It occurs an error while I am trying to click on next page button. It just show the error like this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null".

Here is my code:

```
    var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
    oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';
    this.currentPage = pageNumber;
    var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
    newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';
```

Comment: Well, it's obvious. `getElementById` returned `null` (because it didn't find any element with that ID).

Comment: You should have a dedicated function for setting classes (or use a library).

Comment: @Šime Vidas Why? This may be a one-off usage not requiring a function.  And not every JS problem requires a 100k library to solve.

Comment: @Michael Because the OP has to perform that task (setting a class-name) multiple times. It's called the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @Šime Vidas But we don't know the context of this code. And since it includes `this.` it's likely that it already exists inside a function.

Comment: @Michael Yes, the above code is most certainly inside a function (probably an event handler), but I fail to see why that is relevant. The point I'm making is that setting a class-name based on an ID string is a complex task (it requires multiple statements). Therefore, if that task has to be performed multiple times, in order to avoid redundancy, it (that task) should be isolated into a dedicated function.

Answer (score 3):

It fails because there is no DOM element with the id `'pg'+this.currentPage`.  If this is normal behavior, then you can just wrap the `className` call in an `if` block:

```
var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
if (oldPageAnchor) {
   oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to post more code to show us where `this.currentPage` is set in JavaScript, and the HTML on which it is acting.

Answer (score 0):

`oldPageAnchor` or `newPageAnchor` is null because the element with your specified ID is not found. Check that `this.currentPage` has your desired value AND that the elements that you are trying to find are on the HTML page you're on.