# If page is active, change class of navbar listitem?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If page is active, change class of `nav` `li`?

I've tried this:

```
var page = 'home';
if (page == $("#home").value) {
    $( "#NavHome" ).addClass( "active" );
};
```

And the html:

```
<li id="NavHome">
  Home
</li>
```

On the page itself I made this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="home" value="home">
```

I want if the page is active, the class of `#NavHome` is active, if not, don't set the class to active..

Can someone help me or do you have a better solution?

---

Those doesn't help me:

- [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733660/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-classname-of-null)
- [How to fire an event on class change using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401633/how-to-fire-event-on-class-change-using-jquery)
- [Get the page file name from the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497050/get-the-page-file-name-from-the-address-bar)

Comment: use `$("#home").val()` instead of `$("#home").value`

Answer (score 1):

When checking the value of a jQuery object, use jQuery methods:

```
if (page == $("#home").val()) {
    $("#NavHome").addClass("active");
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/g7tor6md/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
switch ($("#home").val())
{
   case "home":
         $('#NavHome').addClass('active');
         break;
}
```